# New-SelfSignedCertificateEx fails with NTE_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: powershell, encryption, self-signed

I am trying to use PowerShell to create a self-signed certificate for encrypting and decrypting data in a development environment. I am using the excellent `New-SelfSignedCertificateEx` [PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6). My OS is Windows 10 and I have the Windows Management Framework 5.0 installed. Here is the script:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificateEx `
    -Subject "CN=Test, OU=Development" `
    -NotAfter ([DateTime]::Parse('2099-12-31 11:59:59.9999999')) `
    -ProviderName "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" `
    -AlgorithmName ECDH_P256 `
    -KeyLength 4096 `
    -KeySpec Exchange `
    -KeyUsage DataEncipherment `
    -IsCA $false `
    -SignatureAlgorithm SHA256 `
    -FriendlyName Test `
    -StoreLocation LocalMachine `
    -StoreName My `
    -Exportable
```

### Issue #1

Executing the script returns the following error:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificateEx : CertEnroll::CX509PrivateKey::Create: The requested operation is not supported. 0x80090029 (-2146893783 NTE_NOT_SUPPORTED)
At C:\create-self-signed-certificate.ps1:7 char:1
+ New-SelfSignedCertificateEx `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [New-SelfSignedCertificateEx], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,New-SelfSignedCertificateEx
```

I researched the error but couldn't find anything directly related to my problem. I opted to use the Key Storage Provider in lieu of the legacy CSP.

### Issue #2

What values should I use for the `KeySpec`, `KeyUsage`, and `EnhancedKeyUsage` parameters? The purpose of this certificate is only for encrypting and decrypting arbitrary strings (no TLS, no code signing, etc.)

Comment: Of course I figure it out minutes after posting to Stack Overflow... The problem was my key length did not match the required key length of the ECDH_P256 algorithm. KeyLength should be `256`. I also removed the `KeySpec` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you seem to have already discovered, the problem is that you specified a value of 4096 for KeySize while specifying NIST-P256. With RSA and DSA the KeySize is mostly arbitrary, but with Elliptic Curve algorithms the KeySize is forced by the curve's Order (1 <= d <= n, where d is the private key and n is the Order).

So you don't really get to pick KeySize, it falls out of choosing the curve.